# function relations anti symmetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have the following relation $(x,y) \in R$ iff $x=y^2$. The book says it is anti-symmetric but it doesn't show the proof. Can you help me out by showing how to prove it?

Comment: Yes. So my understanding of anti-symmetric  function is that it only contains a pair of points but not it's opposite unless it's the same number am I right?. for example this relation contains (4,2) but not (2,4). but it also contains

Answer (score 1):

You are right.  So suppose $(x,y)∈R$ and $(y,x)∈R$  Then $x=y^2$ and $y=x^2$.  Substitute $x^2$ for $y$ in the first equation to get $x = x^4$.  Can you solve that equation for $x$?

Answer (score 0):

We start with the definition of an antisymmetric relation:

**A relation is antisymmetric if $(x,y)$ is in $R$ and $(y,x)$ is in $R$, then $x = y$.**

An easy way would be to just verify a few examples first, and you can quickly see that the only cases where there is an $(x,y)$ for which $xRy$ and $yRx$ is $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. Notice that $x = y$ in both of these cases, making the relation antisymmetric. The trick is to see if there are any cases that make $x = y^2$ true when $x = y$, or, if there are any cases where $x = x^2$. Hope this helps!